# Can we get the path of a USB drive programmatically(Python) when connected to a raspberry pi?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a small project on Raspberry Pi. I want to make my project as automated as possible. I have a code that saves videos to a USB drive. However, for it to work, I have to hardcode the path of the drive. What I am trying to do is to get a code that will automatically get the path of the USB drive connected to the pi and the videos will be saved to that USB drive. Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `lsusb` command from a command line looks at connected USB devices. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265634/3491475 gives a python3 way to find USB devices (and returns the same data as `lsusb` albeit as (malformed) JSON).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12673589/3491475 gives a method to find mounted devices in a python program. Any filesystem you want to be used must be mounted You can also list that from the command line with a `mount` command.

Comment: @Dougie: FWIW, these *look* like answers & answers get questions closed.

Comment: @seamus - I've reposted my two comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `lsusb` command from a command line looks at connected USB devices.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265634/3491475 gives a python3 way to find USB devices (and returns the same data as lsusb albeit as (malformed) JSON).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12673589/3491475 gives a method to find mounted devices in a python program.

Any filesystem you want to be used must be mounted You can also list that from the command line with a `mount` command.

Comment: Good answer...  :)